# cloneNode is not working in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer-7, clonenode

I have a table that contains multiple rows of having inputs fields.I want to make a clone copy of 2nd or 3rd row my code is here:
but cloneNode is not working in IE7, Please help. This code is working in other major browsers but not working in IE7
    
    
    
    function deleteRow(row)
    {
        var x=document.getElementById('rowcontainer');

```
    var len = parseInt(x.rows.length);
    if(len>4)
    {
        var i=row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById('rowcontainer').deleteRow(i);
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Minimum 3 rows are required');
    }
}


function insRow()
{
    var x=document.getElementById('rowcontainer');

    var len = parseInt(x.rows.length);

    if(len % 2 == 0)
    {
        var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    }
    else
    {
        var new_row = x.rows[2].cloneNode(true);
    }

    x.appendChild( new_row );

    $('#rowcontainer tr:last :input').val('');

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" style="border:solid 1px #d1d1d1; line-height:21px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="rowcontainer">
  <tr style="background:#e0e0e0; line-height:33px;">
    <td class="tblborder" style="width:23px; text-align:center; padding:0px; cursor:pointer;"><div id="addrow" onclick="insRow()">+</div></td>
    <td class="tblborder">Item</td>
    <td class="tblborder">Description</td>
    <td class="tblborder">Quantity</td>
    <td class="tblborder">Unit Price</td>
    <td class="tblborder">Discount</td>
    <td class="tblborder_b" style="text-align:left;">Sub-Total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="background:#f5f5f5;">
    <td class="tblborder" style="background:#e0e0e0; padding:0px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;"><div id="delrow" onclick="deleteRow(this)">-</div></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt desc_item" onclick="openitemdialob();" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt desc_item" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder_b"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" id="subtotalinput" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tblborder" style="background:#e0e0e0; padding:0px; text-align:center; cursor:pointer;"><div id="delrow" onclick="deleteRow(this)">-</div></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt desc_item" onclick="openitemdialob();" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt desc_item" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" /></td>
    <td class="tblborder_b"><input type="text" class="rowinpt subtotal" id="subtotalinput" /></td>
  </tr>



</table>

</body>
</html>
```